# Function receiving an array as parameter

Tags: jquery, arrays, function, parameters

Am trying passing an array as parameter in a function...

```
var arr = ['Célio', 'Elisandro', 'Mariano', 'Garcia'],
    arr = [1, 2, 3, 4],
    za = $('ul'),
    $.x = arr, $.y = arr2;

$.fn.finger = function (x, y){


              console.log(x);


};


for ($.i=0; $.i<arr.length; $.i++){

za.append("<li><a href='#' onclick='$(this).finger($.x[$.i], $.y[$.i]);' >" + $.x[$.i] + "</a></li>");
}
```

My idea is to pass one value of array position when i click of an item the list. but in this case, its return to me all values of array. I want only one..!

Someone have an idea in code?

Comment: why did you write `$.i`.. when it can be just `i`.. you're making it a little hard for yourselves. Also, what is `$.x`?

Comment: ^^ This, but for *all* the times you use `$.`, except where you use it to create the finger function.  Remove all the others.

Comment: @Krishna... am using jquery-1.9.1 and in my logical business, if i don't use $.i, it will return to me: ReferenceError: i is not defined

Comment: @Archer ... you understand me?

Comment: Sorry, but no.  Your question doesn't make sense at all.  It *looks* like you want to create list items with links in them that take values from arrays, but you do not define arrays called `x` or `y` anywhere.  You only have 1 array and that is called `arr` and is not used anywhere in your code, other than to get the length for a loop.

Comment: as for me you should have `za.append("<li><a href='#' onclick='$(this).finger("+$.x[$.i]+","+ $.y[$.i]+");' >" + $.x[$.i] + "</a></li>");`, but make sure variable `$.x` is a bidimensional array.

Comment: @Archer sorry, my mistake ... I've been edited above ...

Comment: @EugenHalca .. cool ... your idea was the best... thanks